# How to print all the instances in a class one by one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to print all the instances of a class one by one?

This is the code:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, age, gender):
       self.fname = fname
       self.lname = lname
       self.age = age
       self.gender = gender

class Children(Person):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, age, gender, friends):
        super().__init__(fname, lname, age, gender)

        self.friends = friends

a100 = Children("a1", "a10", 17, "male", "a2 , a3 , a4 , a5")
a200 = Children("a2", "a20", 17, "male", "a5, a1, a4, a3 ")
a300 = Children("a3", "a30", 17 , "male", "a2, a1")
a400 = Children("a4", "a40", 17, "female", "a1, a2")
a500 = Children("a5", "a50", 16, "male", "a2, a1")

x = ["a100", "a300", "a500", "a200", "a400"]
for n in x:
    print(n.age)
```

Error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex1.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(n.age)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'age'
```

Comment: "How to print all the instances in a class one by one" There are not instances "in your class" unless you put them in there (say, in some class level container like a list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error message suggests, you are trying to access an `age` attribute of a string object. This is because `n` is the loop variable that iterates over the list `x`.

This list consists of strings which you are getting confused with because they represent your variables' "names".

What you want to do is simply change your list to hold the **actual** variables and not their names as strings. Like so:

```py
x = [a100, a300, a500, a200, a400]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for helping. It worked. I see that the key is to understand what the errors means then the answer makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can get those by globals()  - returns map of all current global object like :

```
print([globals()[s].age for s in x])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping can you please explain what it does and where do i put this code

Comment: I like the ides of `globals`, I use it too sometimes. Would be helpful to add some explanations